# HAproxy loadbalancer error 503 Service Unavailable No server is available to handle this request

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ansible, load-balancing, haproxy

i have to make a loadbalancer for two servers hosted on a hostserver.
When i surf to my site it gives a 503 error "Service Unavailable
No server is available to handle this request."

Does someone knows a fix for this?

this is my loadbalancer task

```
---
- name: install HAproxy
apt:
  name: haproxy
  state: latest

- name: copy config
  template:
  src: haproxy.j2
  dest: /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
  notify:
  - restart haproxy

- name: open the listening port
  ufw:
    rule: allow
    port: '80'
    proto: tcp
  notify:
  - restart ufw
```

This is my haproxy template

```
    global
    log         127.0.0.1 local2

    chroot      /var/lib/haproxy
    pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
    maxconn     4000
    user        haproxy
    group       haproxy
    daemon
    # turn on stats unix socket
    stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats

    # utilize system-wide crypto-policies
    ssl-default-bind-ciphers PROFILE=SYSTEM
    ssl-default-server-ciphers PROFILE=SYSTEM

defaults
    mode                    http
    log                     global
    option                  httplog
    option                  dontlognull
    option http-server-close
    option forwardfor       except 127.0.0.0/8
    option                  redispatch
    retries                 3
    timeout http-request    10s
    timeout queue           1m
    timeout connect         10s
    timeout client          1m
    timeout server          1m
    timeout http-keep-alive 10s
    timeout check           10s
    maxconn                 3000

frontend http
    bind *:{{ portloadbalancer }}
    default_backend webservers

backend webservers
    balance roundrobin
    server {{ webservernaam1 }} {{ ipwebserver1 }}:{{ portloadbalancer }}
    server {{ webservernaam2 }} {{ ipwebserver2 }}:{{ portloadbalancer }}

backend app
    balance roundrobin
    server {{ webservernaam1 }} {{ ipwebserver1 }}:{{ portloadbalancer }} check
    server {{ webservernaam2 }} {{ ipwebserver2 }}:{{ portloadbalancer }} check
```

This is my nginx_default_conf

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html;

        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
        }

}
```

the ansible playbook runs it with no problem, also when i watch the logs on my webservers (/var/log/nginx/error.log) there isn't any attempt to connect recorded.

journcal output =>
[image]

haproxy.cfg =>
[image]

Maybe another interesting output
[image]

output ip addr show =>
[image]

output netstat =>
[image]

Comment: Please add `journalctl -xfu haproxy`

Comment: also add, `cat  /etc/haproxy/haproxy.conf` output. NOT the template. Need to see the `bind` section.

Comment: also, what is `portloadbalancer` value ? also what is the output of `netstat -plant |grep $portloadbalancer`

Comment: @P.... the output of the netstat command is "tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN  "

Answer (score 0):

The `journalctl` shows that you are getting permission denied while binding to port `80`; note that port 80 is privileged and requires root permissions for binding. You are running the `haproxy` as a non-root user from the last snippet. Once, you use `root` user, you might need to address the following:

Also, You have used `bind: *:80`, meaning binding on `port 80` for "all" the interfaces. At the same time, you are the same ports for backend servers(again, `port 80`). This is causing the `connection refused` error.

This error has **nothing** to do with ansible, but the issue is with `haproxy` configuration. See example configuration [HERE](https://www.haproxy.org/download/2.7/doc/configuration.txt)(CTRL +F `2.6. Examples`) . In summary, You have two options,

1. Either use different ports for the bind and backends. (for example, 80 and 8080), either by changing `haproxy.cfg` or `nginx.cfg`.
2. Bind to a specific interface IP, not `*.`
   The following are two `netstat` outputs:

***#Example-1: bind to all, same as your current configuration***

Here traffic to any IP address assigned to the machine on port 80 will be load balanced.

```
Proto    Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0    0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      13836/haproxy
```

***#Example-2: when only bind to a single Ip. Here I am only binding a single interface to port 80***

So, only the traffic coming to the `192.168.1.240` on port `80` will be load balanced.

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.240:80        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      14178/haproxy
```

Comment: thanks for answering!
i changed the bind at the frontend to "bind 10.129.25.136:80" that's the ip of my loadbalancer.
i changed the ports in the backend to 8080.
I restarted it after the changes and i got the same errors, any ideas?

Comment: i used the ansible-playbook command with sudo infront, still connection refused.

Comment: try frontend as `*:80` and backend `8080`.

Comment: frontend http
    bind *:80
    default_backend production

backend production
    balance roundrobin
    server {{ webservernaam1 }} {{ ipwebserver1 }}:8080 check
    server {{ webservernaam2 }} {{ ipwebserver2 }}:8080 check

i tried it with this, same errors still

Comment: also, add updated `netstat -plant` and `ip addr show` output.

Comment: Please share the `journalctl -xfu haproxy` output, when you run haproxy with sudo.

Comment: The journalctl output remains the same. added the other outputs.

Comment: "**The journalctl output remains the same.**", still getting connection refused ?  What is the output of  `curl 10.129.25.135:8080`?

Comment: output of curl is also connenction refused & yes, with the journalctl it also gives refuse.

Comment: Then the problem is your nginx; ensure it's up and running. Your backend servers must be individually up and responding to curl; then, only you can load balance them.

Comment: Wondering if, after changing the port from 80 to 8080 on backends, you missed restarting the nginx to pick up the new port?

Comment: i manually restarted the nginx service, they are up and running...

Comment: so, can you add curl output ? `curl 10.129.25.135:8080`  and `curl 10.129.25.135:80` BOTH?

Comment: both outputs are "Failed to connect to 10.129.25.135 port 80 after 0 ms: Connection refused
"

Comment: Then how can you say nginxnbackends are running what test are you doing to confirm that backed servers are running ?

Comment: with systemctl status nginx

Comment: That is not enough to check. It means, Your web server service is running. But on which port ? on your backend server, do `netstat -plant |grep -i nginx` to see if nginx is listening on any port or not.  Also, Please check this https://www.haproxy.com/blog/how-to-enable-health-checks-in-haproxy/#:~:text=about%20each%20one.-,Active%20Health%20Checks,-The%20simplest%20solution

Comment: You have `check` enabled in your backend configuration, but your webservers are not responding on the port(as curl is showing), so haproxy will remove those bad backends from rotation.

Comment: your first step should be to independently make curl run against the backend ports. If only backends are directly accessible, bring haproxy in the flow.

Comment: netstat -plant |grep -i nginx gives nothing as output

Comment: It means nginx is not listening on any port. Any further discussion is probably out of the scope of this discussion. Please validate your nginx configuration and ensure using `curl` and/or `browser` that your backend webserver is running. Unless its running no point of fixing `haproxy` conf.